# Normals on a sphere

Tags: glsl, graphics-programming

I am generating vertices for a sphere by normalizing the vertices of a cube. The coordinates of the vertices are mapped to [-1; 1].

[image: Example].

I want to get the normal vector of each vertex.

My question is do I need to compute the normals, or can I just use the positions of the sphere by just normalizing them? Also, which is more GPU friendly: pre-computing the normals and passing them as an attribute or just calculating them on the go?

```
out_normal = normalize(in_position);
```

Comment: Yes, you can just normalize relative position. Probably precomputing is better, but you'd have to profile to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For normalising on the GPU, it depends on what you want to do.  If you want to do real time transformation (say animate), then yes, go ahead and calculate on the fly in the GPU.  But if it's a once off, just precalc, its better since if you add lots of balls it does add up.

The final thing is just to remember to multiply the 3x3 component of your matrix for your normals once you start rotating or scaling.   But that's the usual.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) For the last part, you mean multiply the inverse 3x3 part of the model matrix with the normal ?

Comment: That is only necessary when scaling though right? The code is for planet generation, so I think I'm only going to deal with spheres...

Comment: your normals will also be affected by rotation and scaling yes.  If you are doing non uniform scaling then your normals will skew depending on the plane you scale in.  Inverse if i remember will return you the original normals in local space (im going off the top of my head).

Comment: I'll add to this: If you want to do any per-fragment ops you'll need to renormalize anyway (normals don't linearly interpolate) so in that case you may as well just do it on the GPU.